Why does a method call affect the object but assignment changes the reference in C#?
I'm working with C# and encountered some confusing syntax. Here's what I have:
public void Foo(StringBuilder sb) {
    sb.Append("test");     
    sb = null; }  

StringBuilder myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); 
Foo(myStringBuilder); 
Console.WriteLine(myStringBuilder.ToString()); // Still prints "test" 

I was expecting that setting `sb = null;` inside the method would also set `myStringBuilder` to `null`, (since sb.Append("test") appends the value to the actual object and not to the pointer), but it didn't. I understand that `sb` is just a copy of the reference, so assigning `null` to it doesn't affect the original object reference.
1. How exactly does this work under the hood? Why does setting `sb` to `null` inside the method not affect the `myStringBuilder` reference outside? (The thing tripping me is the syntax disparity between sb.Append() and sb = null. One changes the object and the other changes the reference)
2. If I really want to set the original object to `null` inside the method, how can I do it? I've heard about using the `ref` keyword but I'm not sure how that changes things.  Any clarification on this syntax and how references work in this context would be greatly appreciated!
I have read up on the issue but could not find a suitable explanation. I have also read about rebinding, assignment and mutation but didn't quite get it.

It's the same as if you did StringBuilder myStringBuilder2 = myStringBuilder; myStringBuilder = null. You copied the reference to the StringBuilder into a new variable, then changed the old variable to reference something else (in this case, null). That doesn't change what object the new variable references

Maybe the confusion is added to by the circumstance that while sb is a reference, it is still passed by value. That means the sb inside your method is a copy of the myStringBuilder reference passed in. So, these are actually two references (pointing to the same object).


You can introduce a wrapper to hold reference and everywhere use that wrapper. Pass wrapper instance as ref and set its member to null.


My question primarily is that sb.Append() operates on the object but sb = null operates on the pointer. Why don't we have to dereference sb or in other words how does sb.Append() dereference sb syntactically? It's  the syntax that's confusing, not the concept. Could anyone please explain?

When method is called sb = myStringBuilder, so you can access myStringBuild members using sb, e.g. sb.Append() is same as myStringBuilder.Append(). You can not change myStringBuilder value by using sb . The only way to assign a new value to myStringBuilder  in method is to make its instance available in the method, e.g. making it a field. To transform object consider to pass it as method parameter and return new instance from method.

Thanks, but let me rephrase my question. In cpp, we have ptr = something to modify the pointer itself, and *ptr to modify the object pointed to by the pointer. But in C#, we are using sb to refer to both: the pointer as well as the referenced object. How does C# know which one is to be used?

"in C#, we are using sb to refer to both" - wrong. sb doesn't know address of myStringBuilder. Related. ref could be called a safe pointer. There is unsafe context with c++ like pointers which I never had to use yet.

You are passing refernce to a object (StringBuilder is reference type) to a method. Method just has own copy of reference inside of it and you only affect the "local reference" - so when you dereference inside method, it only influences the local variable, not undrelying object.
Object reference that you have passed to a function stays unchanged, that's why you are seeing the result in Console.Writeline

sb is a reference to a StringBuilder object.
Assinging null to the reference will simply re-refer sb to null, effectively removing that local reference to the StringBuilder object.
While sb.Append() operates on the referred object.
Your method cannot alter myReference as this is just another reference to the StringBuilder object.
StringBuilder myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

Basically says: Create a new anonymous StringBuilder object and create a StringBuilder reference named myStringBuilder that refers to that object.
